# How to enabling voice communication on Android applications?

Tags: android

Searching a lot on stackoverflow or internet don't find any hint of how to enabling voice communication on Android applications?

Comment: One liner question? Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) @Svel04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found 1 ans :-

Enabling voice communication on Android apps is possible via the `Session Initiation Protocol` (`SIP`) stack. This protocol originated in 2000 as a signaling protocol in support of Voice over IP (`VoIP`)